# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Comment: woot! new theme.

Comment: Can we get a shade of green for [gardening.se]? Everything the same, except it's green... pretty please? :)

Comment: Accepted answers are green :) This is just a theme for all Beta sites. Once this site is close to graduation I'll make sure the final site design is green! So much green that you'll ask me to tone it down.

Comment: and I thought my eyes were going funny...

Comment: +1 for different shades of green. It doesn't have to be brash but with variations, and perhaps only green highlights are required - eg. my site at http://ecomapcostarica.com/ is mainly black and white but has green highlights and a dominantly-green header image.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Gardening & Landscaping design and logo - Information gathering](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/961/37696) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982/37696)