# Your new site design is live!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live!

At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/gardening-landscaping-site-design-and-logo-draft) and for your patience while we got this design out for you.

We really hope you like the design!

Comment: Note: We've noticed a display bug with the background color of the Ask Question page (on both the main and meta sites), and are looking into it now. (UPDATE: This bug is now fixed!)